# How to build an Xpath query in objective-c to get every TR except the first?

Tags: objective-c, xpath

Currently the html I'm parsing looks something like this

```
NSString* markup = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hi</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgAppointmentSearchResult'>
            <tr>
                <th>fail</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>"];
```

Next I'm attempting to get each TR (so I can reach each #2 TD inside each TR) except the first TR has a TH inside it so I want to avoid this.

So far I have the following but notice it only pulls a specific TR / TD combo .. not each of them :(

```
NSData *data = [markup dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
TFHpple* xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];
NSArray *elements  = [xpathParser search:@"
//table[
   @id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgAppointmentSearchResult'
]/tr[2]/td[2]
"];
TFHppleElement *element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *content = [element content];  
[xpathParser release];
[data release];
```

Any help for an Xpath newbie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either:

```
//table[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgAppointmentSearchResult']/tr
    [position() > 1]/td[2]
```

or even more semantic:

```
//table[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dgAppointmentSearchResult']/tr
    [not(th)]/td[2]
```

Comment: +1, but looks a bit confusing with the line break in there.  Might want to put it on one line.